# spring security URL interception: Different behavior in Tomcat 7 and Jboss Wildfly 8

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss, spring-security

please take a look at a part of my security-config.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
    [other stuff here]
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

</http>
```

Let's suppose that the context name of my application is `koko`.

This works fine in Tomcat: When I visit `http://tomcat-url:8080/koko/` or `http://tomcat-url:8080/koko/home` I see a home page asking me to login - after I login I am redirected to `http://tomcat-url:8080/koko/`and I can see link to the other stuff.

When I try to do the same in JBoss, I visit `http://jboss-url:8080/koko/` and I immediately get a login page ! If I visit the `http://jboss-url:8080/koko/home` I see the homepage asking me to login. Now, after I login I am redirected to the `http://jboss-url:8080/koko/` again and I get an Access Denied!! If I manually go to `http://jboss-url:8080/koko/home` after I've logged in I see the other staff and I am able to navigate normally.

So the problem seems to be that JBoss does not understand the line

```
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
```

or it is overriden by the `/**` line that follows. However tomcats works fine with at. This shouldn't be dependent on the Application Server since it is completely spring related and the same spring is used for both applications.

*Update - solution*: Based on @M.Deinum 's answer I added the a new url request mapping named /index.html to my homepage and a permitAll line to that url - and worked fine !

Comment: I suggest you crank up logging and see what happens. My guess is that in JBoss `/` gets remapped to something like `/index.jsp`. JBoss has its own container which might process URIs differently.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you are correct - JBoss for reasons unknown to me tries to find out /koko/index.html when I go to /koko/. Can you add a proper answer so that I could accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat and JBoss have their own implementations (customizations) to the Servlet API.

I would guess that JBoss does some pre processing on the URL and instead of `/` tries to resolve `/index.html`. This is probaly by default (in JBoss) and based on the welcome-file list defined in the web.xml (or to some default).

It's been a while that I worked with JBoss but maybe you can configure this processing somewhere. Historically JBoss used Tomcat as there provider and customized some the the `Valve`s Tomcat uses (to extends/modify behavior).